# How to make external ldap as primary user store in wso2 identity server 5.10.0

Tags: ldap, wso2, apache-directory, wso2-identity-server

I am trying to setup Apache Directory studio as external ldap(Primary user store) in wso2is 5.10.0 with following configuration in deployment.toml file

```
[super_admin]
username = "admin"
password = "admin"
#admin_role = "admin"
create_admin_account = true

[user_store]
type = "read_write_ldap_unique_id"
user_entry_object_class = "inetOrgPerson"
connection_url = "ldap://localhost:10390"
connection_name = "uid=admin,ou=system"
connection_password = "secret"
#scim_enabled = "false"
user_id_attribute = "uid"
user_search_base = "ou=users,ou=system"
base_dn = "ou=system"
```

When i start wso2, ldap connection gets established successfully

```
 INFO {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.UniqueIDReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager} - LDAP connection created successfully in read-write mode
```

but i get the following error in the log before it

```
 ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.UniqueIDReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager} - There is no user with the user name: a9fbdaba-ef0a-422c-a3c7-150d8e62bc44,admin to be added to this role.
```

Also afterwards i get

```
 ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.scim.common.internal.SCIMCommonComponent} - Error occurred while setting SCIM attributes for the Admin org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Error in adding SCIM metadata to the admin in tenant domain: carbon.super
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.scim.common.utils.SCIMCommonUtils.setAdminSCIMAttributes(SCIMCommonUtils.java:250)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.scim.common.internal.SCIMCommonComponent.activate(SCIMCommonComponent.java:79)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:113)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:985)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:151)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:866)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:804)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:228)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:525)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:544)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.core.internal.IdentityCoreServiceComponent.activate(IdentityCoreServiceComponent.java:171)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:113)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:985)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:151)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:866)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:804)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:228)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:525)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:544)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.initializeCarbon(CarbonServerManager.java:529)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.removePendingItem(CarbonServerManager.java:305)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.PreAxis2ConfigItemListener.bundleChanged(PreAxis2ConfigItemListener.java:118)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:973)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:345)
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: userName value is null.
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.callSecure(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:205)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.getUserClaimValue(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:1548)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.scim.common.utils.SCIMCommonUtils.setAdminSCIMAttributes(SCIMCommonUtils.java:231)
        ... 50 more
Caused by: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.callSecure(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:191)
        ... 52 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager$2.run(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:194)
        ... 54 more
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: userName value is null.
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager.getUserPropertyValues(ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager.java:571)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.UniqueIDReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager.getUserPropertyValuesWithID(UniqueIDReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager.java:640)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.doGetUserClaimValuesWithID(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:11346)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.getUserClaimValue(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:1581)
        ... 59 moreanager.
```

The **admin** user gets registered in the ldap but i am not able to login to the management console.

Am i missing any configuration setting or is there any other way to do the same?

**EDIT** : when i use

```
user_id_attribute = "scimId"
```

the ldap connection does not establish and i get the following error

```
ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm} - nullType class java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: nullType class java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.createObjectWithOptions(DefaultRealm.java:397)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.initializeObjects(DefaultRealm.java:224)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.init(DefaultRealm.java:129)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.initializeRealm(DefaultRealmService.java:276)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.<init>(DefaultRealmService.java:102)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.<init>(DefaultRealmService.java:115)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator.startDeploy(Activator.java:72)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.BundleCheckActivator.start(BundleCheckActivator.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:842)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:834)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:791)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:1013)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:365)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:598)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:462)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel$1.run(ModuleContainer.java:1820)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor$2$1.execute(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:150)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1813)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1770)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1735)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1661)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:345)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.createObjectWithOptions(DefaultRealm.java:351)
        ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.util.UserCoreUtil.addDomainToName(UserCoreUtil.java:561)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.addToUserNameCache(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:11877)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.getUserNameFromUserID(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:11842)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.getUserNamesFromUserIDs(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:11916)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.UniqueIDReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.doAddRoleWithID(UniqueIDReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.java:1270)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.addInitialAdminData(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:8410)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager.<init>(ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager.java:246)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.UniqueIDReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager.<init>(UniqueIDReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager.java:148)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.UniqueIDReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.<init>(UniqueIDReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.java:122)
        ... 30 more
```

Comment: Try `user_id_attribute = "scimId"`

Comment: using 'scimId' as 'user_id_attribute' is giving      " ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm} - nullType class java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: nullType class java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException"         and Ldap connection is not even getting established now.

Comment: Are you trying to add an already existing user store?

Comment: No. i'm trying to add an external ldap as user store in wso2

Comment: @ArbazSheikh i am getting the exactly problem as yours. Did you solve in anyway?

Comment: Could you establish a connection from Apache Directory Studio  to ApacheDS (your LDAP server)?

Comment: @ArbazSheikh I'm not using the ApacheDS, but the docker image osixia/openldap. The problem is the same.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I was not able to figure out the problem. I switched to MySql as user store.

Answer (score 1):

[Configure the primary userstore](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.10.0/setup/configuring-a-read-write-ldap-user-store/) in the <IS_HOME>/repository/conf/deployment.toml.

```
[user_store]
type = "read_write_ldap_unique_id"
base_dn = "ou=system"
connection_url = "ldap://localhost:10389"
connection_name = "uid=admin,ou=system"
connection_password = "admin"
<Property-Name> = <Property-Value>
read_groups = true
```

You can use existing user store manager or configure your own custom user store manager as well Writing a [custom user store manager](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/setup/writing-a-custom-user-store-manager)

Now, restart the server.